# Just curios why aurelia is using <equire tag instead of link rel="import" href="component.html"

Tags: aurelia

The Html Imports standard uses `<link rel="import" href="my-component.html">`
What was the reasoning for using the `<require>` tag

The reason I am asking is that my editor supports web components import tag but not the custom require tag

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The require tag gets linked to Aurelias loader.  When you require a path there are some conventions in place that allow Aurelia (or SystemJS) to get multiple resources such as html, js, and css from a single require tag.

This is especially handy for custom elements and cases where you have nested templates containing require tags.  Aurelia is aware of their composition and can determine the exact paths for the resources you requested.

Comment: I see, I know you can add css and js inside a webcomponent but I guess there are other things that Aurelia does with the require tag

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer this myself.  This is what I am seeing at this point.

In September, 2015, Aurelia blogged that ["it has become clear that the HTML Imports part of the specs is not going to become standardized."](http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/09/04/aurelia-early-september-release-notes/)

I've seen comments within github issues that Google is the only one who really wants to standardize HTML imports with the link tag.  While the browser support available seems to support that, I can't verify of the browser supplier's intentions or active support, except [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) who is openly declaring that they have no plans to ship with it.

[W3 github page for webcomponents](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents) indicates, "HTML Modules, rebuilding HTML Imports functionality using the ES Modules, are now being planned."  That's as of January, 2016.

Aurelia's philosophy appears to be to build on top of the web standards as much as possible. However, those (draft) standards are still very much in flux.  I think that Aurelia is just trying to use whatever they expect is most likely to be compliant when the standards are finally published, while also giving themselves as much flexibility to evolve as possible.